# How to subtract rows between two different dataframes and replace original value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction, wrangle

I have two dataframes shown as below. How can I replace Bank1 data by subtracting 10 by 3, and 55 by 2?

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Bank1', 10, 55], ['Bank2', 15,65], ['Bank3', 14,54]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['BankName', 'Value1','Value2'])
```

[image]

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2]], columns = ['Value1','Value2'])
```

[image]

Desired Output(Only replace values in Bank1):

| BankName | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bank1 | **7** | **53** |
| Bank2 | 15 | 65 |
| Bank3 | 14 | 54 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution is create `index` in `df22` by `Bankname` for align by `df1` for correct row subracting:

```
df.set_index('BankName').sub(df2.set_index([['Bank1']]), fill_value=0)

df.set_index('BankName').sub(df2.set_index([['Bank2']]), fill_value=0)
```

You need create new column to `df2` with `BankName`, convert `BankName` to `index` in both `DataFrame`s, so possible subtract by this row:

```
df22 = df2.assign(BankName = 'Bank1').set_index('BankName')
df = df1.set_index('BankName').sub(df22, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)
  BankName  Value1  Value2
0    Bank1     7.0    53.0
1    Bank2    15.0    65.0
2    Bank3    14.0    54.0
```

Subtract by `Bank2`:

```
df22 = df2.assign(BankName = 'Bank2').set_index('BankName')
df = df1.set_index('BankName').sub(df22, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df)

  BankName  Value1  Value2
0    Bank1    10.0    55.0
1    Bank2    12.0    63.0
2    Bank3    14.0    54.0
```

Another solution with filter by `BankName`:

```
m = df1['BankName']=='Bank1'
df1.loc[m, df2.columns] = df1.loc[m, df2.columns].sub(df2.iloc[0])
print (df1)
  BankName  Value1  Value2
0    Bank1       7      53
1    Bank2      15      65
2    Bank3      14      54

m = df1['BankName']=='Bank2'
df1.loc[m, df2.columns] = df1.loc[m, df2.columns].sub(df2.iloc[0])
```

Comment: I think your previous method works for me, I don't need to create another column. df.set_index('BankName').sub(df2.set_index([['Bank1']]), fill_value=0)

Answer (score 3):

try, using [`sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html#pandas-dataframe-sub) + [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first)

```
df1.sub(df2).combine_first(df1)
```

---

```
  BankName  Value1  Value2
0    Bank1     7.0    53.0
1    Bank2    15.0    65.0
2    Bank3    14.0    54.0
```

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity. What if I want to subtract and replace the second row? This combine_first seems to be only applicable to the first row

Comment: @Jamie I thought about the same problem but your df2 does not have any indicator of the bank.  So I wonder how you could tell which row to delete from.

Comment: @sushanth I've learnt sub and combinefirst... had not used these before. Thanks!

Comment: @Sushanth. Yes, this is actually a real issue I encountered today. df2 doesn't have any indicator of the bank name, but I know which row in df1 I want to subtract by df2, so no indicator is needed